# Extending Decimal in order to use rounding(accordingToBehavior:)

Tags: swift, math

I'm working with numbers of type `Decimal` in Swift. I would like to use `rounding(accordingToBehavior:)` with my numbers and for that I believe I need to write an extension to `Decimal` to use this method of `NSDecimalNumber`. I'm not sure how to do that, as I've never written an extension before. Any thoughts ?

Comment: I don't get what you are asking. `Decimal` is the Swift's overlay for `NSDecimalNumber`. Converting between them takes some CPU time, but functionally, they are equivalent. Can you give an example of what you want to do?

Comment: var testingNSDecimalNumber: NSDecimalNumber = 8.765
testingNSDecimalNumber.rounding(accordingToBehavior: <#T##NSDecimalNumberBehaviors?#>)

Comment: If var testingDecimalNumber: Decimal = 8.765 is a Decimal I cannot invoke .rounding(accordingToBehavior:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try something like this.

```
let testingNSDecimalNumber: NSDecimalNumber = 8.765 
let numberHandler = NSDecimalNumberHandler(roundingMode: .plain, scale: 2, raiseOnExactness: false, raiseOnOverflow: false, raiseOnUnderflow: false, raiseOnDivideByZero: false)
let roundedDecimalNumber = testingNSDecimalNumber.rounding(accordingToBehavior: numberHandler)
```

If you want to create `extension` of `NSDecimalNumber` then you can try like this.

```
extension NSDecimalNumber {
    func makeRoundingNumber(with scale: Int16) -> NSDecimalNumber {
        let numberHandler = NSDecimalNumberHandler(roundingMode: .plain, scale: scale, raiseOnExactness: false, raiseOnOverflow: false, raiseOnUnderflow: false, raiseOnDivideByZero: false)
        return self.rounding(accordingToBehavior: numberHandler)
    }
}
```

Now call this extension's method this way.

```
let testingNSDecimalNumber: NSDecimalNumber = 8.765
print(testingNSDecimalNumber.makeRoundingNumber(with: 2))
```

**Edit:** For your comment `If var testingDecimalNumber: Decimal = 8.765 is a Decimal I cannot invoke .rounding(accordingToBehavior:)` you can try like this.

```
extension Decimal {
    func makeRoundingNumber(with scale: Int16) -> NSDecimalNumber {
        let numberHandler = NSDecimalNumberHandler(roundingMode: .plain, scale: scale, raiseOnExactness: false, raiseOnOverflow: false, raiseOnUnderflow: false, raiseOnDivideByZero: false)
        return NSDecimalNumber(decimal: self).rounding(accordingToBehavior: numberHandler)
    }
}
```

Now call it like this way.

```
var testingDecimalNumber: Decimal = 8.765
print(testingDecimalNumber.makeRoundingNumber(with: 2))
```

Comment: Hi Nirav, yes, thank you very much. I used your code to extend Decimal and now everything working perfectly !

Comment: @fbelfort Welcome mate :)